# RxJs - conditional subscription chain with maps and operators instead of nesting

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular6

I'm trying to set up an RxJs recipe to perform some steps and do operations conditionally based on the result of some subscriptions.

The pseudo-code is:

```
  if (trySocialSign() succeeds) {
     if (tryGetUserFromDatabase() succeeds) {
         do.some.stuff
         return
     } else {
         do.other.stuff
     }
  }
```

Right now I have this ugly function that works but I'm wondering if there's a prettier way using pipes and maps and other rxjs operators to be able to achieve the same effect in a more idiomatic way with less nesting. Can someone please help me?

```
this.auth.getCurrentUserAsync().subscribe(
  (u: EasyAuthUser) => {
    this.currentUser = u;

    this.users.getUser().subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        this.onExistingUserSignIn.emit(user);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (redirected) {
          this.onSignIn.emit(u);
        }
      }
    );
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {this.handleHttpError(err)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like the following code (I didn't test it for obvious reasons). All side-effects are performed only from `let`. There's also one `catchError` that will suppress the inner error.

```
this.auth.getCurrentUserAsync().pipe(
  let((u: EasyAuthUser) => this.currentUser = u),
  mergeMap((u: EasyAuthUser) => this.users.getUser().pipe(
    let(
      (user: User) => this.onExistingUserSignIn.emit(user),
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (redirected) {
          this.onSignIn.emit(u);
        }
      }
    ),
    catchError(e => empty()), // Maybe you don't even want this `catchError`
  ))
).subscribe(
  user => ...,
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleHttpError(err),
);
```